# How do I handover a image file in react native as URI, since require just returns a number?

Tags: android, image, uri, react-native

I am looking for a solution to handover a image URI to a native module in Android.
The problem is, that when I require a image in react native, it just returns a number.

So I'd need to load the URI directly or some sort of string that can be converted to a file and afterwards to URI in android.

EDIT:

My images are loaded in a separat file like this:

```
{ sticker1: { uri: require('./Sticker_1.png'), path: './Sticker_1.png' } },
```

Afterwards I display items in a Flatlist like this:

```
renderItem(item) {
const itemIndex = item.index;
const itemKey = `sticker${itemIndex + 1}`;
const sticker = item.item[itemKey];

return (
  <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => this.handOverSticker()}
    key={itemKey}
  >
      <Image source={sticker.uri} style={styles.previewImage} key={itemKey} />
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
}
```

So far everything works.
handOverSTicker function looks like this:

```
handOverSticker(sticker) {
  this.props.handleUseSticker(sticker);
}
```

The other component then takes care of the URI in a react native module in android and does other stuff. The problem is the received URI being the returned number by require.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
   let imgUrl = props.image ? { uri: props.image } : require("../assets/images/image.jpg");
 this.state = { image: imgUrl };
}
```

In source of Image place this code:

```
source={this.state.image}
```

Comment: But like this my require image is still a number.
I need to import the image to send it to a react native module without being a number, or atleast the path of the image which can be handled in android/iOS.

Comment: pass the parameter in

Comment: onPress={() => this.handOverSticker()

Comment: if this doesn't work, show the console.log(item) of renderItem

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot the parameter, but that still take me to the result, that the android modul give me the error: double cant be casted to string (because of the number from require).

Comment: {item: {…}, index: 0, separators: {…}}
index: 0
item:
sticker1: {uri: 45, path: "./Sticker_1.png"}
__proto__: Object
separators: {highlight: ƒ, unhighlight: ƒ, updateProps: ƒ}
__proto__: Object

Comment: we use uri in Image when our image is on server,
if your image is on local, then use require in Image.

I guess your image is on local

Comment: Yes my image is on the local storage in react-native. But I need the uri in android. Do I have to save the image on the device for this, so that I can get the uri via a FileProvider or so? 
I hoped that I could get that uri another way, because that image has to be saved somewhere else inside the app-structure. I just don't know how to access it from the android module, when I for example pass the image name.